Is there a workaround for filtering by frameId a declarativeNetRequest rule?
I'm developing a web extension for Google Chrome, and I need to extend the declarativeNetRequest rule only to certain frames without it spreading to all other frames. However, ruleCondition does not have the frameId property. I submitted a feature request about this, but it’s not clear when it will be implemented. Are there any workarounds to solve this problem? Considering that the frame url can be anything.
UPD: It looks like the only full option is to wait for feature request to be implemented, so please vote for it if you want to bring it closer to implementation

There's no good workaround. One is chrome.debugger API, but it may have its own bugs. Another one is installing the extension via policy so it can use webRequestBlocking.
